# Is it possible to re-scope an imported Maven dependency in the same pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I'm working in an application server environment in which I'm using a bom to gather the dependency information like so:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

However, this particular bom specifies a dependency as "compile" that I wish to have scoped for all of my projects as "provided".  However, when I attempt to override the scope in the same pom from which I'm importing the dependency like so:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-federation</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Maven complains that it cannot find the version, or if I use the version property specified in the bom, the property cannot be found.

I'm fairly certain this is an issue with the import + override in the same pom, because I can override the scope in child projects just fine.  Is there a way to both import and override the scope in a single pom?

*all code snippets above come from the same  section.

Comment: When you say "all code snippets above come from the same section", do you mean that the dependency to `org.picketlink:picketlink-federation` is declared in the `<dependencyManagement>` section?

Comment: yes, I do.  The problem is that I'm working in a parent pom that will be shared by several children.  I don't want to have to override in each of the children, so I'd ideally like to override the scope imported from the bom in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly doable:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   ...
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security</artifactId>
     <version>${jboss.bom.version}</version>
     <type>pom</type>
     <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
   ...
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
   ...
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
     <artifactId>picketlink-federation</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Just remember that you need to redefine your scopes in the `<dependencies>`and **not** in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

Your scope override will of course propagate to any child POMs, if you use inheritance.

Comment: Hi Daniel - see comment above.  This won't work because I need the picketlink-federation dependency declared in the <dependencyManagement> section.  I have several child projects inheriting from this one that may or may not need that particular dependency, so placing it here would give me unused declared dependencies in several projects.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I don't think that's the way this is supposed to work. If you import dependencies from somewhere it means that you are conforming to their view of the world. I don't think you can get away with not overriding the scope in each of the child modules.

That being said, you could create your own BOM, change it to suit you needs and inherit from that. This particular BOM only lists about 10 dependencies, so it's definitely manageable.

Comment: yeah... so I'm hoping for a "best practice-y" way to do it.  That bom only has about 10 deps, but it inherits from a parent with lots more.  I'd like to *not* be in the business of maintaining that if possible.  It stands to reason that for something like an Application Server, one would be able to tweak the boms for a few small configuration changes without having to re-implement the entire thing...

Comment: I agree. But the problem is, since you are indeed customizing it, you are nonetheless stuck with maintaining it anyway. For every new release or upgrade, you need to go through the dependencies and see if there are any other dependencies whose scope need to be tweaked. I'm afraid that this is closest thing to best practice as we'll ever come.

Comment: I think we might just agree to disagree on this one :)

Comment: :) Fair enough. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.